# objective-c callback function errors with EXC_BAD_ACCESS

Tags: ios, objective-c, callback, objective-c-blocks

I have the following callback function:

```
void(^getImageCallback)(BOOL success,  UIImage *image , NSError *error);

- (void)getRemoteImageWithObjectId:(NSString *)objectId andType:(NSString *)type andSaveLocal:(BOOL)saveLocal withCallback:(GAGetImageCompletionBlock)callback{
    getImageCallback = callback;

    [self getRemoteImageWithObjectId:objectId andType:type shouldSaveLocal:saveLocal];

}

- (void)getRemoteImageWithObjectId:(NSString *)objectId andType:(NSString *)type shouldSaveLocal:(BOOL)saveLocal{

    UIImage *image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"running.png"];
    getImageCallback(YES, image, nil); //it errors out here
}
```

My app crashes here with error: `Thread 1: EXC_BAD_ACCESS (code=1, address=0x10)`

Does anyone know why this might happen?

Comment: Please show how you have declared "getImageCallback".

Comment: A EXC_BAD_ACCESS signal is the result of passing an invalid pointer to a system call, so you might be dereferencing a null pointer somewhere.

Comment: More information is needed for people to be able to help you. Are you using MRC or ARC? At the point it errors out what is the value of `getImageCallback`? If it is `nil` what is the value of `callback` that is assigned to it in `getImageCallback = callback`?

Answer (score 0):

You might call the 2nd `getRemoteImageWithObjectId` method instead of the 1st `getRemoteImageWithObjectId` method. So `getImageCallback` variable was nil at that time. The reason of `EXC_BAD_ACCESS (code=1, address=0x10)` might be calling the nil `getImageCallback` block.

For example, if you compile and execute the following Objective-C code on 64bit environment, you got the exactly same EXC_BAD_ACCESS with address=0x10.

```
void (^block)() = 0;
block();
```

You can double check this code in C++ with clang `-rewrite-objc` option. This Objective-C code was compiled as the following C++ code.

```
struct __block_impl {
    void *isa;      // offset:0x00
    int Flags;      // offset:0x08
    int Reserved;   // offset:0x0c
    void *FuncPtr;  // offset:0x10
};

void (*block)() = 0;
((void (*)(__block_impl *))((__block_impl *)block)->FuncPtr)((__block_impl *)block);
```

Now `block` variable is 0 (nil), so `block->FuncPtr` points address `0x10`. Thus  `EXC_BAD_ACCESS (code=1, address=0x10)` was occurred.

LLVM document says the same thing. http://clang.llvm.org/docs/Block-ABI-Apple.html#high-level

```
struct Block_literal_1 {
    void *isa; // initialized to &_NSConcreteStackBlock or &_NSConcreteGlobalBlock
    int flags;
    int reserved;
    void (*invoke)(void *, ...);
```